# Pie chart howto in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I was wondering if there is an option to create pie charts in Rascal.
It could be done by making separate pie slices but there is no angular option with the ellipse() method. There was a former Wedge() method, but that has been removed from the library.

Answer (score 1):

The *short* answer: in the currently distributed visualization library  of Rascal there is no possibility to draw pie charts.

The *longer* answer: we are working on a new version that includes Google Charts (and hence also pie charts). Unfortunately, that does not solve your problem today.